# What is the name of the css property that draw dotted rectangle to show keyboard focused element?

Tags: css, terminology

What is the name of the CSS property that draws a dotted rectangle to show an element that has the 'keyboard focus'?

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `outline`. Or use `outline-style`, `outline-width`, `outline-color`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline